# Password no more working on a vista session: is that possible?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I try to help my friend with his vista laptop but cannot figure out what can be the cause of this problem.

He has 2 users on his vista laptop, each been secured with a password.

On the first session (non admin user), no pb to login in (the password is a current word from the dictionnary).

On the second session (admin user), he had some problem login during the last weeks: sometimes the password was not recognized and sometimes it was (sometimes, after a couple of reboot, the login was successful). Now it seems the login is not possible anymore (at least 20 reboot but nothing changed). The password for this session is quite complexe one (something like ZZ@abc5).

My first though was that:
- a key from the keyboard might be damaged and preventing the password from been entered correctly => we have checked and this is not the case
- the keyboard language was changed (EN instead of FR) => also checked this and this is not the cas
- I've tested to use the visual keyboard but same thing.
- I've used the "safe mode" but this is the same thing

As this happens for an admin user, this is quite annoying.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the origin of the problem but I manage to get rid of it by clearing the user's password using an Ubuntu live CD and the chntpw utility.